# UIImagePickerController Cropping with allowEditing doesn't work for landscape images

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I use UIImagePickerController with allowEditing set to true to pick a picture from the phone's gallery, but when the image is landscape, the cropping is useless because the crop area includes the whole picture like in the screenshot below. Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You can't solve this using the image picker. You will need to roll your own cropping or choose from an open source one.